# gzip: stdin: not in gzip format when installing No-IP DUC

Tags: static-ip

I am trying to install No-IP on my Pi 3B through Putty. I do the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar xzf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz.1
```

But I get the error

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What am I doing wrong? I am completely new to both Linux and Pi. I am using Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: If you typed the first 2 lines I would expect an error message because you wouldn't have write permission.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
wget http://noip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
```

Their url scheme changed

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded the "archive" and got the same error like you. Inspecting the file I found it isn't an archive not at all. It is a clear text file containing a html web page. Rename it and you should be able to open it in a web browser (I haven't done that ;-).

```
~$ mv noip-duc-linux.tar.gz noip-duc-linux.html
```